# BigQuery | How to select * from previously defined CTE in the same query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, common-table-expression

I have the below SQL query which I want to run on BigQuery.
I am constantly getting error : **Unrecognized name: nojoin** on the start of the select statement of CTE named **onejoin**.
Please help. It works for uom_conversion.* in nojoin CTE but nojoin.* doesnt work in onejoin CTE.

```
WITH uom_conversion AS
(
select a.*,
case when a.sales_unit in ('EA','ZIN') and b.unit = 'CSE' then ifnull(a.order_quan*b.bic_zconvfac,0.0) else a.order_quan end as cse_order_quan,
from `dev-amea-analyt-datal-svc-db.dev_amea_h_sapbw_ptc_otc.v_sales_order_items_amea` as a
left join `dev-amea-analyt-datal-svc-db.dev_amea_h_sapbw_mst.v_mat_unit_otc_amea` as b
on a.material = b.material and a.sales_unit = b.bic_zaltunit
),
nojoin AS
(
SELECT uom_conversion.*,
case when unit_of_wt = 'KG' and doc_type = 'ZOR' then net_wgt_dl end as ship_ord_kg_mysg_osa
from uom_conversion
),
onejoin AS
(
SELECT nojoin.*,
case when orders.doc_type = 'ZOR' and orders.reason_rej = '0' and delivs.biczdelv_itm = '0' and orders.unit_of_wt = 'KG' then orders.net_wgt_dl end as ship_ooqty_kg_mysg_osa
from nojoin as orders
left join `dev-amea-analyt-datal-svc-db.dev_amea_r_sapbw_ap_ptc_otc.v_sales_delivery_items_ap` delivs
on orders.doc_number = delivs.doc_number
),
twojoins AS
(
SELECT onejoin.*
case when orders.doc_type = 'ZOR' and orders.reason_rej = '0' and delivs.biczdelv_itm != '0' and bills.bill_num = '' and orders.unit_of_wt = 'KG' then orders.net_wgt_dl end as ship_nsord_kg_mysg_osa,
from onejoin as orders
left join `dev-amea-analyt-datal-svc-db.dev_amea_r_sapbw_ap_ptc_otc.v_sales_delivery_items_ap` as delivs
on orders.doc_number = delivs.doc_number
left join `dev-amea-analyt-datal-svc-db.dev_amea_r_sapbw_ap_ptc_otc.v_sales_billing_items_ap` as bills
on orders.doc_number = bills.doc_number
)
SELECT *
from twojoins
```

Comment: remove all `with` except of the first one!

Comment: I am sorry, its already removed...this was typing error from my side while asking the question. Below is the actual code.

`WITH uom AS (select a.*, few_derived_columns from table1 a left join table2 b on` `a.col1 = b.col1), nojoin AS (select uom.*, few_derived_columns from uom), onejoin AS` `(select nojoin.*, few_derived_columns from nojoin), twojoins AS (select oneojoin.*,` `few_derived_columns from onejoin) select * from twojoins /*** Need all the existing` `columns from table1 and all the derived columns from all the CTEs ***/ `

Comment: so what the problem then?! your case works perfectly for me! with exception of misspelled `oneojoin.*` - should be `onejoin.*`

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. Please find the actual code here [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jvs3xMRfPLKuCfnqdUg_zEWecNdCvQl7/view?usp=sharing)
Also the corresponding snip from BigQuery showing the error [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hz5dG-QaI-T-1HFP477-8N6d-xvAridN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please include your query and error message as part of the question; instead of providing external links

Comment: You need to use `orders.*` instead of `nojoin.*` since you provided a table alias in the `from` clause. You made that error elsewhere in your query too; see if you can find it

Comment: Perfect, Thank you. It works. Only thing is, is there any other way to optimize this query ?
Its taking ages to run, given the size of the v_sales_order_items_amea table is around 82 GB.

Comment: @VikasTiwari I am sure there is but that's out of scope of this question AND we know next to nothing about your data or business question. For a start, think about how you can avoid joining to the same table multiple times. Also consider sub-selecting those rows and columns you actually need